# Reusable Button with image tag (React Native)

Tags: react-native

I want to turn this section of code into a reusable component so I don't have to write the same thing out 5 times.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={console.log('pressed')}>
  <Image
    source={require('../img/button_australia.png')}
  />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

The new component I made to mirror this is as follows:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const ImgButton = ({ onPress, img }) => {

return (
  <TouchableOpacity onPress={onPress}>
    <Image
      source={require(img)}
    />
  </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export { ImgButton };
```

After importing this component ImgButton I call it with this block of code:

```
  <ImgButton
     onPress={console.log("pressed")}
     img={'../img/button_australia.png'}
  />
```

I get the error: "Requiring unknown module '../img/button_australia.png'"

I assume I've gone wrong when passing the string down as a prop but from the examples I've looked I don't see what's wrong with what I've done. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in [this react-native issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/6391), it's not possible to `require` assets or javascript modules with dynamically generated names, e.g. variables.

This is because the React Native packager uses `require` (and `import`)  statements to generate the module and asset bundles at compile-time, so the value of the variable is not known.

The simplest way is to just pass the image source to the component directly:

```
<ImgButton
  onPress={console.log("pressed")}
  img={require('../img/button_australia.png')}
/>
```